# Performance improvement on Linux VM(heavy multi threaded app)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, virtualbox

Hi after doing some profiling on the application I get the following stack of kernel calls, being at the top of the application. The rest of the execution is really low on CPU usage (between 0.x - 2%, green zone).

The code (C++) on Linux (VM VirtualBox) time set to hpet (can be seen in the calls) The app (5 threads) dealing with 100 TXNs /second (TCP/DB writings...) Is there a way to tune the **gettimeofday** or is the hypervisor of Virtual Box really bad. CPU load on htop ... is around 30-40% on the machine. (4 Cores i7 + 6GB RAM)

Samples: 128K of event 'cpu-clock', Event count (approx.): 32221750000 Overhead Command Shared Object Symbol

```
14.52% app [kernel.kallsyms] [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
    _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
        8.82% hrtimer_start_range_ns
            8.79% do_nanosleep
                hrtimer_nanosleep
                compat_sys_nanosleep
                sysenter_dispatch
        4.22% try_to_wake_up
        1.06% __wake_up_sync_key

**13.47% app [kernel.kallsyms] [k] read_hpet**
    read_hpet
    12.10% __getnstimeofday64
        getnstimeofday64
            10.28% do_gettimeofday
                compat_sys_gettimeofday
                sysenter_dispatch
            1.70% ktime_get_real
    1.36% ktime_get

11.67% app [kernel.kallsyms] [k] native_sched_clock
    native_sched_clock
        11.67% sched_clock
            local_clock
                9.92% tcp_transmit_skb
                    tcp_write_xmit
                    __tcp_push_pending_frames
                    tcp_push
```

Here is some of the rest of the calls. This application is pretty big, I didn't want to add all the perf data, but here is a bigger snippet:

```
+   14.52%  app   [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
+   13.47%  app   [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] read_hpet                  
+   11.67%  app   [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] native_sched_clock         
+    9.81%  app   [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] finish_task_switch               
+    1.25%  app   libc-2.17.so                  [.] __memcpy_ssse3                               
+    0.90%  app   libc-2.17.so                  [.] __memcmp_sse4_2            
+    0.85%  app   [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] __do_softirq     
     0.84%  app   app                        [.] list<var_entry>::find                     
+    0.81%  app   libc-2.17.so                  [.] __strlen_sse2_bsf              
+    0.66%  app   app                        [.] __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx          
+    0.63%  app   libclntsh.so.11.1             [.] kpuexec                        
+    0.51%  app   libclntsh.so.11.1             [.] ttcfour                        
     0.48%  app   app                        [.] str_base::is_null
```

Also the reddit link for the same question (maybe better text format)

> https://www.reddit.com/r/AskProgramming/comments/8dm5mb/performance_improvement_on_linux_vmheavy_multi/

Comment: So the next step you need to take is create a minimal example.  In this case it would likely be a simple loop calling just getTimeOfDay with a sleep in it.  This will then demonstrate that your high cpu time in that function is because it's slow, rather than because you're calling it in a tight loop.  As things stand, you could've run 5 threads doing `while (1) {getTimeOfDay();}`  (if that wasn't UB in itself)

Comment: This is not the case ... but I will update my initial perf trace by adding more of the application layer.
Also, to create a minimal example would imply cache performance hitting and by that I mean it will be out of the real world example. I'm not blaming directly the gettimeofday call, as I said it can be the hypervisor of Virtual Box ...

Comment: Or it could be an issue with your threads.  If you create a single threaded program that calls getTimeOfDay and you measure the performance of that and it has no problems; then you know your problem is related to the fact that your threads are spending all their time in the spin lock as suggested by your edit.

Comment: Ehm ... if you just do what you said (single threaded application), you will get into cache prediction where it would just make it as fast as possible. The thing is, this is an existing application working on a huge load what I mean is you can exclude locks or useless spins. I'm asking for a tuning solution. If you have something to help, then I listen, but let's not waste time in blaming.

Comment: Well, you can make your own function, for example my_gettimeofday(), which will actually call gettimeofday() on every, for example 10000th call, and reset a local static atomic timer each time it calls it. Between the two gettimeofday() calls you can calculate the time of day based on the timer elapsed time since the last call to gettimeofday(). But, then again, the timer code might be slower than gettimeofday(), no way to know that until you test it.

Comment: @BJovke thanks for the idea, will try it out

Answer (score 1):

It was the hypervisor of VBox, it's not up to the task :(. After running it on a normal server on KVM all is good.

Comment: I'm currently suffering the same issue of `_raw_spin_unlock_irqstore` high CPU usage with my Java application. Do you have any thoughts on why it can have so high CPU usage?